# No krb5.keytab file on Linux (SLES) Machine

Tags: linux, cryptography, sap, kerberos, keytab

I'm trying to implement single sign on for our SAP System. On the first 3 machines I've got no problems. But now things seems a little bit different:

If I try to write my host keytab file into the krb5.keytab via ktutil an error occures:
No such file or directory while writing keytab "/etc/krb5.keytab".
I tried to create the missing krb5.keytab and tried it again:
Unsupported key table format version number while writing keytab /etc/krb5

I already installed everything from our SoftwareCenter which relates to MIT krb5. But for this issue I have no clue where to start.

Do you know, where or how I'm able to create a krb5.keytab which works?! Or do I have to configure something on the SAP site?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

it's not necessary to have the /etc/krb5.keytab. If you already generate a Keytab from the DomainServer you have to edit the path on /etc/krb5.conf from the default (/etc/krb5.keytab) to your keytab file. It works fine now.